# How to retrieve subclasses of the class type in python3?

Tags: python

In python3,   `object` is a base for all classes.

```
>>> object
<class 'object'>
>>> object.mro()
[<class 'object'>]
# it makes sense.
```

However:

```
>>> object.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> object.__subclasses__()
[<class 'type'>, ....]
```

class 'type' is object's supclass and subclass.

> defination of `__class__` in official documentation python 3.6.2
>
> - ``` instance.``__class__ ```
>
>   The class to which a class instance belongs.

try 'type'

```
>>> type
<class 'type'>
>>> type.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> type.__subclasses__
<method '__subclasses__' of 'type' objects>
```

error occurs then:

```
>>> type.__subclasses__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor '__subclasses__' of 'type' object needs an argument
```

How to retrieve the subclasses of class type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't sufficient documentation for `__subclasses__` around. However, it appears calling that dunder from `type` requires an **instance** of the '*type*' object:

```
>>> type.__subclasses__(type) # 'type' is an instance of itself
[<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>, <class 'enum.EnumMeta'>, <class '__main__.a'>]
```

In fact, `type.__subclasses__(obj)` can be used instead of calling the method directly from `obj` since every object is an instance of `type`:

```
>>> int.__subclasses__()
[<class 'bool'>, <enum 'IntEnum'>, ...]
>>> type.__subclasses__(int)
[<class 'bool'>, <enum 'IntEnum'>, ...]
```

And the behaviour is *also* consistent with object `object`, so that:

```
type.__subclasses__(object) == object.__subclasses__()
```